# Automated WordPress update failed to complete - but all updates fail with code -1

Tags: updates, debug, automatic-updates, wp-debug

I have a WordPress website on my Ubuntu machine. I do use auto-updates and auto-updates for plugins. After I logged in recently I saw that a couple of plugins didn't update, as well as WordPress itself.

[image: update plugin]

When I try to update the Duplicate Page plugin for example I get the following Error:

[image]

Ok so good, I enable the debug mode by adding these three lines to my *wp-config*:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
```

But even after re-generating the error, I don't get any debug file in my wp folder.

I restarted nginx, even the machine itself and played around with the maintenance file, but no luck so far.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you aware of WP CLI, and are you able to run updates via CLI?

Comment: Have you looked at the PHP log files?

Comment: where do I find them? Didn't find ANY log

Answer (score 1):

This is a shot in the dark, so apologies if i am wrong, but i think i remember having this error code a while ago, and if my memory is correct, running the update on the Updates page instead of the plugins page fixed it for me. Doesnt help for auto updates but might help you find an answer

Comment: I was able to update my main WP, but not my plugins using this idea.

Answer (score 1):

Another shot in the dark here, but I'm wondering if the log files not being created relates to the plugin update issue. I'm thinking there might be permission issues keeping WordPress from being able to modify files.

Verify the user for you server (nginx/apache is www-data) and then make sure this user has permissions over the folders and that [WordPress file permissions](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/proper-wordpress-filesystem-permissions-ownerships/) are set accordingly.